# Persisting DataTable or GridView DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a Click Event  that fills a DataTable and the DataTable is the source of my GridView.

Then I have another click event that tries to get the GridView DataSource e converts it back to a DataTable Like:

`DataTable dt = (DataTable)GridView1.DataSource;`

But the Datasource returns null. Event if I put the code and the Page_Init event waiting for the right postBack

so I would like to know how can i persist the datasource of the gridview, or the DataTable

edited as required:

here is the whole code:

ps: the Page_Init was another try to get the datasource

```
    private DataTable _dataTable;

    public DataTable dataTable
    {
        get { return _dataTable; }
        set { _dataTable = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string ctrlname = BLL.Common.GetPostBackControlId(this.Page);

            if(ctrlname == "ButtonDownload")
            {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)GridView1.DataSource;
            }
        }
    }


    protected void Filter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] status = new string[2];
        status[0] = "Paga";
        status[1] = "Disponivél";

        dataTable = BLL.PagSeguro.GetTransactions(TextBoxInicio.Text, TextBoxFim.Text, status);

        GridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


    protected void GetDataSource(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)GridView1.DataSource;
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the event and the code where you set the DataSource?

Comment: edited the post with the code

Comment: I see what you are doing; you are trying to persist the data beyond the page life cycle; and the code I provided below will help you get there but will require re-loading the data.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

```
public partial class Demo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private DataTable _myData = null;
    protected DataTable MyData
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == _myData)
            {
                // You would load your data here.
                _myData = new DataTable();
            }
            return _myData;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Lets say you set your data source here
        myGrid.DataSource = this.MyData;
    }

    protected void Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This is some other event that also needs to get at the data.
        DataTable mydata = this.MyData;
    }

    protected void Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != _myData)
        {
            _myData.Dispose();
            _myData = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can only access the datasource that way through the `DataBound` event or `ItemDataBound` event. You might be able to access the DataRowView for each item in the `Items` collection, but I'm not sure:

```
DataRow row = ((DataRowView)GridView1.Rows[0].DataItem).Row;
```

As for persisting the datasource, you need to consider whether that's a good idea. Your options for storing the datasource are `Session` or `Cache`, but if the result set is fairly small it might be more efficient to make another round trip when you need the datasource. Whatever you decide to do, don't store it in ViewState.